# How to integrate FontAwsome library with my Magento store ?

Tags: magento, font-awesome-4

I have been trying to integrate Font Awesome library into my Magento store. I have been trying to add CSS links onto my Local.xml file but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Please provide CSS code for how you tried to link font awesome and that font-files are reachable from your HTML

Answer (score 5):

Paste the following code into the `<head>` section of your Magento `head.phtml`.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

**OR**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="yourLocalPath/font-awesome.min.css">
```

**OR**

you can go to `System` > `Configuration` > `Design` > `HTML head` > `Miscellaneous Scripts` and can add the above link.